# hiding select options and show them after clicking a defined one

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-select

This is my example.

```
<select name="mydropdownbox">
<option value="val1">val1</option>
<option value="val2">val2</option>
<option value="val3">val3</option>
<option value="val4">val4</option>
<option value="val5">val5</option>
<option value="val6">val6</option>
</select>​
```

as you can see, we have a select box with different options.
What i want to do is to hide option with val2 and val5, but add another option to the end of the list like `<option value="more">more</option>`.

By clicking "more" the hidden options should be shown. the option "more" should be replaced by an option "less". By clicking less the options should be hidden again.

Please keep in mind that this is only an example. The full list contains more than 50 options. Would it be useful to some kind of array?

Unfortunately I have no idea how to start.
Any help on this would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

**UPDATE**
Please have a look at my comments in the js-Part http://jsfiddle.net/bqyBQ/5/

Comment: I believe that to "hide" option elements you'll need to actually remove them, because some browsers don't allow you to hide them through CSS.

Comment: hm, so there would be no way to show them again?

Comment: Select element may not be that flexible to your requirements, you may want to consider a check box list and add a little js and css to allow easy selection and visual indication of what is selected

Comment: i'd like to but the list is a country list and i get the data from the server.

Comment: To show them again you append them back. If you're using jQuery you can remove them with the [`.detach()` method](http://api.jquery.com/detach/) and keep a reference to them ready to re-append later.

Comment: Hi, this is where I'm hanging http://jsfiddle.net/bqyBQ/5/. Help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try something like this

```
<select id="mydropdownbox" name="mydropdownbox">
    <option value="val1">val1</option>
    <option value="val2">val2</option>
    <option value="val3">val3</option>
    <option value="val4" class="hide">val4</option>
    <option value="val5" class="hide">val5</option>
    <option value="val6" class="hide">val6</option>
    <option value="more" class="more">more</option>
</select>​

<style type="text/css">
  .hide { display: none; }
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
  jQuery('#mydropdownbox .more').click(function() { 
    jQuery('#mydropdownbox .hide').attr('class', 'show');
  });
</script>
```

Just put a new class to these elements, which should be hidden per default. Then add a click event to the more link to toggle these classes. It would be easy to make a less button with this technique too.

Answer (score 0):

Make a link in the "more" option. on click of more option should  call javascript or jquery and add the data dynamically from the script  and toggle the caption of more and less as well as add and remove operation

Comment: i'm new to javascript. have you got an example?